# CultureInfo.CurrentCulture always return en-US when publish Asp.net core angular 9 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization, cultureinfo, currentculture

I am using localization in my asp.net core angular 9 application. currently I am dealing with two languages (English, German). In controller class I am getting culture info by this globalization method.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetCurrentCultureName")]
    public string GetCurrentCultureName()
    {
        CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
        return culture.Name;
    }
```

If I add German language and get culture in visual studio, it gives **"de-De"** which is correct, but when publish application it always return **"en-US"** irrespective of current system language.
Please help me.[Add Language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxAed.jpg)

Comment: Could you share more code? Where and how do you set Culture? Can you clarify what you mean by "I add German language"?

Comment: Milan I am getting current culture of window.
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetCurrentCultureName")]
        public string GetCurrentCultureName()
        {
            CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
            return culture.Name;
        }

Comment: I have edited my post described how I am adding new language.

Comment: Where and how do you set Culture? Did you just add localization files in project or did you actually set culture somehow? Can you take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: I have set German culture by adding German language and make it display language. I have also attached screen shot in post. Please check.

Comment: You should think of your application as (almost) independent system from OS. In your case you have added German to Windows but it is not needed to make switching culture in application. Your application may be hosted on Linux or another Windows which does not have German.

Please, try to read article I mentioned in previous comment. Read it at least 2 - 3 times to get a good grip of it. After that if you do not understand something come back and ask.